# Code not working, getting syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
import random

correct= 0
print ("Hello, Welcome to the Quiz!")
name = input("What is your name?")
class_no = ""
while class_no not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
    class_no =  input("Please enter your class - 1,2 or 3:")
print ("Welcome to this maths quiz, while answering the questions please take in mind:")
print ("That + is addition, - subtraction and * is multiplication")
print ("Also please only enter numbers and make sure you do not leave an answer blank, Thank you!")
for count in range(10):
    num1 = random.randint(1,20)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)
    symbol = random.choice(["+","-","*"])
    print("Please solve :\n",num1,symbol,num2)
    user = int(input(""))

    if symbol == "+":
        answer = num1 + num2
    elif symbol == "-":
        answer = num1 - num2
    elif symbol == "*":
        answer = num1 * num2


    if user == answer:
        print("Correct!")
        correct = correct + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")

print(name ,"You Got ",correct, "Out of 10")

with open("class%s.txt" % class_no, "a") as my_class:
    my_class.write("{0}\n".format([name,correct]))

viewscores= input("Please select a class from 1,2 or 3 and press space and choose one from alphabetically, average or highest?")
if viewscores=='1 alphabetically':    
     with open('class1.txt', 'r') as r:
           print(line, end=' ')
```

What i am trying to do is make the code alphabetically sort the results which are saved onto a separate text file.
Im still getting an error something about the line not being defined, so is there anything wrong the my whole code, Thank you for any help.
This is the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "E:\GCSE COMPUTING\task 3 trial.py", line 41, in

```
print(line, end=' ')
```

NameError: name 'line' is not defined

Comment: `withoopen` should be `with open`. You're missing the space between.

Comment: You should always share your errors.  We can debug very quickly reading these syntax errors.  You should also read the errors closely, they usually tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your error:

```
 withopen('class1.txt', 'r') as r:
     print(line, end=' ')
```

You should use `with open(file, mode) as r:`, like in the following code:

```
viewscores= input("Please select a class from 1,2 or 3 and press space and choose one from alphabetically, average or highest?")
if viewscores=='1 alphabetically':    
    with open('class1.txt', 'r') as r:
        print(line, end=' ')
```

Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html).